# Dropdown menu flip position issue. React-Select + Material-UI Popper

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, flip, react-select

I use the example autocomplete field from the Material-UI lib documentation. (https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#react-select)

There is a problem with fliping the menu when it opens at the bottom of the page or the browser's viewport.

Is there a way to fix this problem with Material-UI and react-select?
Or do I need to write something custom?

Comment: What do you mean with "fliping"? Can you provide a screenshot and the code?

Answer (score 6):

If you are not using a `<Menu/>` custom component, you can use the `menuPlacement="auto"` prop of `<Select/>`, then your problem is solved.

```
const components = {
  Control,
  // Menu , <-- delete it
  NoOptionsMessage,
  Option,
  Placeholder,
  SingleValue,
  ValueContainer
};
```

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/403

Otherwise you can choose another selector, material-ui provides 2 more differents integration with the `<Popper/>` component: react-autosuggest and downshift.

https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

i've faced the same problem, for `<Select />` component i have used what TomLgls suggest, but for `<AsyncSelect />` as a work-around, i used some offset calculations in my component :

```
const rootHeight =  document.getElementById('root').offsetHeight ;
const selectElement = document.getElementById('async_select_container_id');
const selectOffsetBottom=  selectElement.offsetHeight  + selectElement.offsetTop;
...
<AsyncSelect 
  {...listProps}
  menuPlacement={
      rootHeight - selectOffsetBottom > 210 ? 'auto' : 'top'  // react-select menu height is 200px in my case
  }
/>
```

i hope it helps as well

Answer (score 0):

If you have created customMenu component then in that give className as open-menu-top and write this code for class:

```css
.menu-open-top {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

Your CustomMenu maybe look like this:

```js
const CustomMenu = ({ children, innerProps, innerRef, selectProps }) => {
      return (
        <div
          ref={innerRef}
          {...innerProps}
          
          className={`rs-menu ${customMenuClass} open-menu-top`}
        >
         {Your Logic}
        </div>
      );
    };
```